# Modular Arithmetic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Can someone please explain why if: $15m+7 \equiv 4 \pmod 7$, then it is equivalent to saying $1m+0 \equiv 4 \pmod 7$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, since $\,15=1\pmod 7\;,\;\;7=0\pmod 7\,$

Answer (score 1):

Since we are adding $7$ to $15m$, it doesn't change the resultant at all (we are working in $\pmod 7$).

Now we have that $15m \equiv 4 \pmod{7}$, which is $7 \cdot 2 \cdot m \equiv 4 \pmod{7}$, implying that $m \equiv 4 \pmod{7}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of facts that you should have seen by now (all congrunces modulo the same modulus $n$):
\begin{align}
\text{if}\>a\equiv a'\>\text{and}\>b\equiv b'\>\text{then}&a+b\equiv a'+b'\\
\text{if}\>a\equiv a'\>\text{and}\>b\equiv b'\>\text{then}&ab\equiv a'b'\,.
\end{align}
With these in hand, you should be able to see the answer to your question.